# Block right clicks in canvas with WebGL context

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, webgl

I want to stop the right mouse button on a HTML5 canvas bringing up the context menu, since it gets in the way of mouse-controlled games.

I've tried adding `oncontextmenu="return false;"` to the `canvas` tag attributes.  This works when the canvas is using a 2D context, but *not* when it uses a WebGL context, in both Firefox and Chrome.

Is this somehow specified by the standard or is it two simultaneous browser bugs?  Is there any way to work around this and block right clicks in a WebGL context?

Comment: you need to do it with the old way rightclick handler (e.preventDefault(), e.stopPropagation())

Comment: since this really isn't a WebGL question why not edit the question to something more generic like "block right clicks in browser" or "prevent context menu in browser"? Just an idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Results may vary per browser so ensure this works on all targeted browsers. I only tried it in Chrome.

```
  yourCanvas.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
      if (e.button === 2) {
       e.preventDefault();
        return false;
      }
  }, false);
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/cK9Rt/

(it will say "test" in the console but not make the context menu)

Comment: I tried that on Chrome 15 and it doesn't work at all.  The function doesn't seem to ever be called.

Comment: Also how's construct going? Saw your latest post on HN about it. I'd love to know how things are going and what kinds of issues you two are facing.

Comment: Huh, thats odd, your jsfiddle code works but not when I paste it in to my code.  I'll have a play around.  Construct's going well, do pop by the forum and say hi if you like :)

Comment: Excellent article: [Stop Misusing Return False](http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/).

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code when blocking a default browser action

```
element.onevent=function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

This code makes absolutely sure that the default action will not occur

never use html attributes to prevent the default.

When I saw your question, I tried this under the same circumstances:

```
canvas.oncontextmenu=function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

And it worked exactly as it should.

I hope this helps any future viewers of this question